# call multiple view controller in didSelectrow uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, didselectrowatindexpath

i am using two protocol something like this:

```
@protocol ModalClosedProtocol <NSObject>

-(void) modalClosedGlobalProtocolMethod;

@end
```

and  syncmlClient Protocol.

There are three classes `ContactsViewController`, `EventViewController`, `ImageSettingViewController`.These classes use `ModalclosedProtocol` and syncmlClient protocol.all these three classes expects from `SettingViewController` class to implement `ModalClosedProtocol` and syncmlClient protocol.It is just a short overview of current implementation.
In my `SettingViewController` i am handling table delegate method `didSelectRow`.for code factoring i have created a separate method which is called from `didSelectRow`.. like this:

```
    -(void) checkDeviceAndHandleModelSizeForFlip:(FlipsideViewController *)flipVc orContact:(ContactsViewController *)contactVc orEvent:(EventViewController *)eventVc orImage:(ImageSettingViewController *)imageSettingVc
{  
    UIViewController *genericVC;  
    if (flipVc!=nil)  
    {  
        genericVC = flipVc;  
        flipVc.modalClosedProtocolDelegate = self;  
        flipVc.syncmlClient = self.syncmlClient; 

    }  
    else if (contactVc!=nil)  
    {
        genericVC = contactVc;  
        contactVc.modalClosedProtocolDelegate = self;  
        contactVc.syncmlClient = self.syncmlClient;  
        contactVc.mainViewController = self.mainViewController;  
    }  
    else if (eventVc!=nil)  
    {  
        genericVC = eventVc;  
        eventVc.modalClosedProtocolDelegate = self;  
        eventVc.syncmlClient = self.syncmlClient;  
        eventVc.mainViewController = self.mainViewController;  
    }  
    else if (imageSettingVc!=nil)  
    {
        genericVC = imageSettingVc;
        imageSettingVc.modalClosedProtocolDelegate = self;
        imageSettingVc.syncmlClient = self.syncmlClient;
        imageSettingVc.mainViewController = self.mainViewController;

    }

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        genericVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        [self presentViewController:genericVC  animated:YES completion:nil];
        genericVC.view.superview.frame = CGRectInset(genericVC.view.superview.frame, 100, 50);
    }
    else
    {
        genericVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentViewController:genericVC  animated:YES completion:nil]; //alok

    }
}
```

basically if you see there is lot of redudancy in code in `if/else` clause.It would be better from code management point of view if i had a single `UIViewController` object.

```
genericVC = contactVc;//vc object passed from didSelectrow it may be contact/event/image  
    genericVC.modalClosedProtocolDelegate = self;  
    genericVC.syncmlClient = self.syncmlClient;  
    genericVC.mainViewController = self.mainViewController;
```

can some one help me regarding this problem.
  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare your genericVC like this:

```
UIViewController<ModalClosedProtocol, syncmlClient> *genericVC;
```

This way you let the compiler know that your genericVC View Controller conforms to the protocols ModalClosedProtocol and syncmlClient, so the methods you want to call are there.

Comment: you are right however the arguments passed should also declared same like you suggested otherwise you will get incompatible viewcontrooler erro

Comment: i just have to change method definitionlike this:-(void) checkDeviceAndHandleModelSizeForFlip:(FlipsideViewController<ModalClosedProtocol,SyncMLClientDelegate> *)flipVc orContact:

Comment: then simply:  UIViewController<ModalClosedProtocol, syncmlClient> *genericVC;
    if (viewController!=nil)
    {
        genericVC = viewController;
        viewController.modalClosedProtocolDelegate = self;
        viewController.syncmlClient = self.syncmlClient;
        viewController.mainViewController = self.mainViewController;

    }

Comment: You should change `-(void) checkDeviceAndHandleModelSizeForFlip:(FlipsideViewController *)flipVc orContact:(ContactsViewController *)contactVc orEvent:(EventViewController *)eventVc orImage:(ImageSettingViewController *)imageSettingVc` to `-(void) checkDeviceAndHandleModelSizeForGeneric:(UIViewController<ModalClosedProtocol‌​,SyncMLClientDelegate> *)genericVc` and then add `<ModalClosedProtocol‌​,SyncMLClientDelegate>` in every .h (Flip, Contact, etc)

Comment: people like you are helping community to grow together, i have done already.thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
[self checkDeviceAndHandleModelSizeForFlip:self.flipVc];//Pass contactVc, eventVc, imageSettingVc like that,

-(void) checkDeviceAndHandleModelSizeForFlip:(ViewController *)viewController
{
    UIViewController *genericVC;
    if (viewController!=nil)
    {
        genericVC = viewController;
        viewController.modalClosedProtocolDelegate = self;
        viewController.syncmlClient = self.syncmlClient;
        viewController.mainViewController = self.mainViewController;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what i have treid very first but got the error: Property 'modalClosedProtocolDelegate' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'

Comment: or you pass as "id" type instead of viewcontroller.

Comment: Property 'modalClosedProtocolDelegate' not found on object of type '__strong id'

Comment: basically it could be done:if i take suppose myViewController:UIViewController<modalClosedProtocol,SynclMlClientProtocol>.Now simple myViewController *genericVC;
    if (viewController!=nil)
    {
        genericVC = viewController;
        viewController.modalClosedProtocolDelegate = self;
        viewController.syncmlClient = self.syncmlClient;
        viewController.mainViewController = self.mainViewController;

    }

Comment: but that doesn't make sense to create an another UIViewController subclass just adopting protocol..there must be some other better way

Comment: Are you using like this, @property(nonatomic, assign) id <ModalClosedProtocol> delegate;

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <ModalClosedProtocol>

Comment: thanks for help you can see my comments on @gwiz answer below to find solution.